Error trying to use edge-js: path.resolve is not a function
I am trying to use the edge-js library in node.js with react.
At first I got the following error:
ERROR in ./node_modules/edge-js/lib/edge.js 2:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in ...

After looking through stack overflow, I was able to fix this by adding the following lines to webpack.config.js:
fallback: {
   "fs": false,
   "path": false,

},

This seemed to work because the error disappeared but a new error showed up in its place and I don't know how to solve this one:
path.resolve is not a function
TypeError: path.resolve is not a function

Does anyone know what to do? I have never used edge-js and I am confused on what to do next.
